# How Can I Update a Single Instance of a Class Across Many View Controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, oop

Good morning,

I'm designing an application that be used to conduct surveys. A user will open the application, create a "New" survey, answer the associated questions, and then receive some output.

The survey is rather convoluted. Basically, the person is going to be answering the same series of questions about each of their family members. Once the questions are complete, the user will allow the application to take all of that information and perform a certain number of calculations and return a result.

I have a class, called "Survey," which contains properties for the user's basic information (Name, Email Address, etc). I also have a class called "indQuestions," which contains properties that need to have values set for each member of the family (Each one will have a height, weight, DOB, income, etc). Based on the size of the family, the Survey instance will have any number of instances of "indQuestions."

Now, I have to create a single instance of Survey when a new survey is created, but that instance of Survey has to contain X number of instances of indQuestions, and multiple Surveys need to be created based on whether the user wants to do a second survey, change answers to compare returned values, etc for whatever reason.

My application contains many UIViewControllers, since the survey is long and not everything can fit on one page, but the survey is cumulative, and it requires me to be able to access information on each UIViewController that was entered in previous UIViewControllers.

I considered creating a Singleton instance of my Survey class, but ultimately, there has to be multiple instances of Survey, since the customer may opt to do the survey multiple times. Also, the customer has to be able to add an unknown number of instances of "indQuestions" to accommodate the size of the family. Ive been wracking my brain trying to figure out how to find a way to both make a single instance of Survey (and its associated values) available across multiple views while also allowing for the dynamic creation of multiple family members.

I would appreciate any guidance that you can provide. I don't know how to progress with this.

Follow up: 
Okay, so I assume I'd use the following instance to create a new survey?

```
+ (instancetype)startNewSurvey {
  static Survey *_instance;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    _instance = [[Survey alloc] init];
  });
  return _instance;
}
@end
```

Would I then use the activateSurvey method to pass the startNewSurvey instance into activeSurvey? I'm trying to follow the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you could really benefit from using an sqlite database for your `Survey`s, but if it's too much work or falls too far out of the design of your application, you could use this kind of strategy:

```
@interface Survey : NSObject
+ (instancetype)startNewSurvey;
+ (instancetype)activeSurvey;
+ (NSArray *)allSurveys;
+ (void)removeSurvey:(Survey *)survey;
+ (void)activateSurvey:(Survey *)survey;

@property (strong) NSMutableArray *indQuestionsObjects;
@end
```

It allows you to effectively have a singleton, but track multiple instances at the same time. Rough implementation follows:

```
@implementation Survey
static Survey *__activeSurvey = nil;
static NSMutableArray *__allSurveys = nil;
+ (instancetype)startNewSurvey {
  if (!__allSurveys) {
    __allSurveys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  }
  Survey *survey = [[Survey alloc] init];
  [__allSurveys addObject:survey];
  return survey;
}
+ (instancetype)activeSurvey {
  if (!__activeSurvey) {
    __activeSurvey = [self startNewSurvey];
  }
  return __activeSurvey;
}
+ (NSArray *)allSurveys {
  return __allSurveys;
}
+ (void)removeSurvey:(Survey *)survey {
  if (survey) {
    [__allSurveys removeObject:survey];
  }
}
+ (void)activateSurvey:(Survey *)survey {
  __activeSurvey = survey;
}

- (instancetype)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    _indQuestionsObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  }
  return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: Would this method allow me to create multiple instances of indQuestions within that Singleton?

Comment: I misunderstood your `indQuestions`. Convention indicates that names starting with a lowercase letter are variable names, not class names. I had assumed you already had a property for these. I'll update the answer for your usage.

Comment: I've updated the origin post with a question/codeblock.

Comment: No, you won't be able to use `dispatch_once` with this. It is not a true singleton, but it will behave *like* a singleton, allowing you access to a single active instance throughout your application.

Comment: I'm going to play with this and figure out how it works. Thank you so much for your help. I'm very new to all of this, and I'm being asked to make an application that is a bit out of my league, so the help is very much appreciated.